# Можно ли запретить автоматическую перерисовку DevExpress TreeList при добавлении узла?

Tags: devexpress, .net

Узлы добавляются уже после запуска, алгорим, отвечающий за получение нового узла, сам по себе довольно громоздкий, вместе с перерисовкой получается довольно долгий запуск. Можно ли как-то заблокировать автоперерисовку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эти два метода заюзай в паре BeginUpdate EndUpdate. Можешь о них вот тут почитать.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_BeginUpdatetopic

Кстати, а почему не в суппорт с этим? Они бы тебе точно ответили.

Comment: В итоге обратился в саппорт, именно это и посоветовали, но в то время у меня не было прав ответить на свой вопрос самому)